# Print inventory data

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I want to print inventory data:

```
const inventory = require('./cars.js');

console.log(inventory[id])
```

the data is like this:

```
let inventory = [
  { id: 1, car_make: 'Lincoln', car_model: 'Navigator', car_year: 2009 },
  { id: 2, car_make: 'Mazda', car_model: 'Miata MX-5', car_year: 2001 },
  {
    id: 3,
    car_make: 'Land Rover',
    car_model: 'Defender Ice Edition',
    car_year: 2010,
  },
];
```

Comment: What is the question? Is something not working? Please read [ask] and [edit] your post.

Comment: i want to print inventory specific data

Comment: What do you mean by specific data? Do you want to print an object with a specific `id`?

Comment: yes without using filter reduce map

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your inventory list and look up the item by ID.

```js
const inventory = [
  {
    id: 1,
    car_make: "Lincoln",
    car_model: "Navigator",
    car_year: 2009,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    car_make: "Mazda",
    car_model: "Miata MX-5",
    car_year: 2001,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    car_make: "Land Rover",
    car_model: "Defender Ice Edition",
    car_year: 2010,
  },
];

function getInventoryById(inventory, inventoryId) {
  return inventory.find(item => item.id === inventoryId);
}

const item = getInventoryById(inventory, 3)

// item:
// {
//   id: 3,
//   car_make: 'Land Rover',
//   car_model: 'Defender Ice Edition',
//   car_year: 2010
// }
```